# Need to enlarge image at click and then reduce it again by clicking again on external javascript file

Tags: javascript

This large image is defined in the *index.html* with a `class="small"` attribute so it shows as a thumbnail.

```
<img id="smart_thumbnail" class="small" src="https://image.jpg">
```

On a separate .js file need to create a function to bring it back to it's normal size and then back to thumbnail by clicking it again. NEED to use *if/else*. What I am trying to do is to switch between `class=""` and `class="small"`

So far I have this but it is not working:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

    var thumbnailElement = document.getElementById("smart_thumbnail");
    thumbnailElement.addEventListener("click", function() {

        if(thumbnailElement.className = "small";){thumbnailElement.className = "";}
        else
        {thumbnailElement.className = "small";}
    });

});
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: `if (thumbnailElement.className = "small")` needs to be `if (thumbnailElement.className == "small")`

Comment: Dave, Good catch, exactly. Flavio, today we use `classList`, in order not to override other stylistic classNames added to an Element.

Comment: you're doing it the other way around. A thumbnail should not have a "small" className. It should have *any* className than defines its styles inside its component. Rather on click assign a ***bool modifier*** className such as "is-active". And than use JS's `Element.classList.toggle("is-active", isActiveBool)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that I made work. It uses JS style properties to change it, not CSS classes. You could copy or reference it:

```js
var imgEl = document.getElementById("Img");
var isBig = false;

imgEl.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (isBig) {
    imgEl.style.width = "30px";
    imgEl.style.height = "30px";
    isBig = false;
  } else {
    imgEl.style.width = "100px";
    imgEl.style.height = "100px";
    isBig = true;
  }
})
```

```css
#Img {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: red;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div id="Img">
```

The CSS class switcher isn't working because '=' is not an equal operator, it is an assignment operator. use '==' or '===' for equal operators.

Answer (score -1):

The code above will only run once when the website is initially loaded. To solve this problem, you will need to modify the code so that it is constantly listening for an event.
The code for it should look something similar to the following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Resizing a square with event listeners</title>
 <style type="text/css">
  .small {
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
  }
  .large {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
  }
  #smart_thumbnail {
   background-color: blue;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="smart_thumbnail" class="large"></div>
<script>
    var thumbnailElement = document.getElementById("smart_thumbnail");
    thumbnailElement.addEventListener("click", function() {
        if (this.className == "small") {this.className = "large";}
        else {this.className = "small";}
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I also modified the smart_thumbnail so that it has a large/normal size class as well as a small class.